# Convert date value

Tags: sql, datetime

in sql i have this datetime

```
 2014-08-18 00:00:00.0000000
```

and need to convert this:    Monday, August 18, 2014

i used this code it worked but missing letter with month

```
   select   (datename(dw, a.start_date)+ ', ' + convert  (varchar(30),a.start_date,107) )as newdate,
           start_date
      from km.schedule
```

this come out as : Monday, Aug 18, 2014

Comment: Formatting dates is 1, pretty specific to each database product and 2, better done in your client or reporting app; On the assumption this is SQL Server, `Format(GetDate(), 'dddd MMMM dd, yyyy')`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sql query :

```
SELECT FORMAT('2014-08-18 00:00:00.0000000', 'dddd, MMMM d, yyyy') AS ConvertedDateTime;
```